# PHP arrays - display unused vars

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have

```
<?php 

$type[ford][focus] = 'some text';
$type[ford][fiesta] = 'some text';

$type[toyota][corola] = 'some text';
$type[toyota][avensis] = 'some text';

$type[bmw][x6] = 'some text';
$type[bmw][x5] = 'some text';

$type[audi][a6] = 'some text';
$type[audi][a8] = 'some text';



function show($car){

foreach ($car as $model)
{
echo $model;
}

}



echo 'Best cars';
show ( $type[bmw] );

echo 'Other cars';
show ( $type[ford] );


?>
```

What I need is that the rest of cars that are not used (audi and toyota) to be displayed in the last function. So show ( $type[ford] ) should display ford, audi and toyota cars.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **Quote your array keys if they're strings.** `$type[ford]` is wrong, as you would see if you activated error reporting. That needs to be `$type['ford']`.

Comment: @LoWE: Do you understand recursion? If so, then [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) is all you need. If not, try reading an article like [this](http://www.elated.com/articles/php-recursive-functions/).

Comment: @André: I must have misunderstood the question completely, but I don't see what recursion has to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a copy of the original variable here, but you can modify the original too if it's not used anymore after this.

```
$cars = $type;

echo 'Best cars';
show ( $type[ 'bmw' ] );
unset( $cars[ 'bmw' ] );

echo 'Other cars';
foreach( $cars as $car ) {
    show( $car );
}
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to reuse the foreach in show(), making it a recursive function.

Comment: @André: I would like to see an example. I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how the items in the array are 'used' as the function isn't in the code but I would recommend using `unset()` in the function then all that's left in the array is items that are unused.

Answer (score 0):

Also using unset(), but rewriting show() to do the work:

```
function show($car){
  foreach ($car as $model)
  {
    if(is_array($model)) {
      show($model);
    } else {
      echo $model;
    }
  }
}

$cars = $type;

echo 'Best cars';
show ( $type[ 'bmw' ] );
unset( $cars[ 'bmw' ] );

echo 'Other cars';
show($cars);
```

This way, you could change $cars to have more levels (for example, the year of the model) and you wouldn't have to change the code.

Comment: Interesting! Not sure if I would use it here, but I can see uses in other cases.